# Bootstrap fade class blocking hidden.bs.modal event bootstrap 3.0.21

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, triggers, modal-dialog

I'm using Bootstrap and I'm facing an issue when I trying to fire an event on closing my modal, if I have the fade class in the modal the event doesn't get fired, but if I remove it everything works fine.

I want the animation and I want the trigger and I don't want to use any workaround such as create my own fade class or manually trigger hide events.... I want to use bootstraps classes and events.

```html
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" id ="alertModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4> bli</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <h2 >blabla</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal"> bla</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

```js
    postRender: function() {
                    $('#alertModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
                        alert("test");
                    });
                    this.startModal();
                },
                startModal: function() {
                    this.$el.modal({
                        keyboard: false
                    });
                }
...
```

Again, if I remove the fade class, it all works perfectly.

**Update**

solved...see answer.

Comment: Possibly you're encountering https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/13031 ?

Comment: I cant change the boostrap file or take a newer bootstrap.js file... any other ideas?

Comment: That constraint is *really* stupid.

Comment: Please do not use "bootstrap" tag, use "twitter-bootstrap" since it means something else

Comment: @cvrebert- the restrictions are mandatory due to the fact that I am working for a company and changing bootstrap file or getting a newer version will not be allowed... but I will ask again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLVED**

Solved it by just setting the trigger when the Modal is defined.

```
postRender: function() {
            this.startModal();
        },
        startModal: function() {
            this.$el.modal({
                keyboard: false
            }).on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
                alert("test");
            });
        },
```

apparently the if you try to set a trigger to the event after the modal is created the trigger gets blocked by the fade class. but like this it works. still not 100% sure why

but works and tested.